# How to set Themes in Windows Application as in Web?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am Creating a Windows Application in which there numerous forms. I want to create a general theme for all forms like style sheets or theme files in webapplication. Is there any way for setting themes in Windows application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is something that lacks support in WinForms. There are [third party controls](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/NET/Controls/WinForms/Skins/) allowing you to achieve this but nothing out of the box. This concept has been [introduced in WPF](http://wpfthemes.codeplex.com/) which is intended to replace WinForms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `third party dll` to change theme of your windows form like [DotnetSkin](http://www.dotnetskin.net), [DevExpress](http://www.devexpress.com) etc.